# Как изменить прозрачность элемента при прокрутке страницы?

Tags: html, css, html5, scss

Есть текст на странице, у него opacity стоит 0, и как только пользователь его увидит (к примеру прокрутит страницу) то у него должна стать opacity 1 с неким transition, как такое сделать?

Comment: Вариантов много, смотря что Вы используете в своём проекте. Есть ли js, да и вообще каким языком или фреймом пользуетесь?

Comment: @Denis640Kb нужно только усилями css, или так нельзя? Никаким, просто осваиваю стили.

Comment: Изменить-то можно, тут главный вопрос - как отследить тот момент, что клиент его просмотрел. Изменить при наведении на картинку можно, но как это обыграть таким образом, чтобы она менялась фиксированно, даже не знаю, может ребята ещё подскажут. Если на js или jquery - это просто.

Comment: @Denis640Kb можете привести код на js или же jquery как ответ? Мне так же пойдет, но было бы на чистом css было бы прикольно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, такой вариант:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.opacity').each(function() {
      var self = $(this),
        height = self.offset().top + self.height();
      if ($(document).scrollTop() + windowHeight >= height) {
        self.addClass('active').delay(100).css({
          "opacity": "1"
        })
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.opacity {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="opacity">Есть текст на странице, у него opacity стоит 0, и как только пользователь его увидит (к примеру прокрутит страницу) то у него должна стать opacity 1 с неким transition, как такое сделать?</div>
<div class="block"></div>
```